# Сброс нажатых radio и checkbox. Ограничение на количество нажатых checkbox

Tags: javascript

Создаю учебный тест на javascript и нужно сделать при функции backstart() сбрасывались нажатые checkbox и radio. Еще нужно сделать что бы пользователю можно было поставить флажок только на 3 из 5 чекбоксов  в одном вопросе.

```js
var rez=0,
d=document;
function v3(){
  for(i=0; i<d.getElementsByName("q3").length; i++){

      if(d.getElementsByName("q3")[i].checked) {

        if(i==0){rez+=2;}
        if(i==2){rez+=2;}
        if(i==3){rez+=1;}
      }

  }
alert(rez);

}
```

```html
<div id="v3" class="qdiv">
          <p class="quest">Для облика древнейшего человека характерны:</p><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="1" />выступающие челюсти</label><br><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="2" />прямая походка</label><br><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="3" />прыгающая походка</label><br><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="4" />руки, свисающие ниже колен</label><br><br>
          <a href="#" onclick="v3()" class="btnflip">
             ответить
          </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Мне нужно сделать сброс всех нажатых checkbox и radio при нажатии на кнопку. и сделать ограницение на количество нажатых chekbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio'],input[type='checkbox']").
  forEach(el => el.checked = false);
```

2.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".qdiv input[type='checkbox']").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if (this.checked) {
      var count = this.closest(".qdiv").querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
      if (count > 3)
        this.checked = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="v3" class="qdiv">
  <p class="quest">Для облика древнейшего человека характерны:</p><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="1" />выступающие челюсти</label><br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="2" />прямая походка</label><br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="3" />прыгающая походка</label><br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="4" />руки, свисающие ниже колен</label><br><br>
  <a href="#" onclick="v3()" class="btnflip">
    <span class="btnflip-item btnflip__front">Ответить</span>
    <span class="btnflip-item btnflip__center"></span>
    <span class="btnflip-item btnflip__back">Далее</span>
  </a>
</div>
```